# Track app installs received from a mobile browser

Tags: android, mobile, google-play, google-analytics-api

I have a mobile web app (opened on Android's browser, not a native one), that redirects the user to Google's Play store (for apps install). I want to track the app install (Assuming the user opened Google Play's native app and not web Google Play) to know that I was the referrer for that install. I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986320/android-app-a-wants-to-track-google-play-referral-data-for-android-app-b-install) and [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/devguide#general-campaign-tracking), but they are all taking about referring to Google play from within a native Android app. Do we have a solution for tracking app install that was referred from mobile browser?

Comment: One solution I could think about is getting the referrer when installing the app ("using com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"???) and firing a pixel to our server. The problem is that I couldn't find decent documentation for that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the app to display the webpage, you can use the same app to get list of app installed :

Try this :

```
    final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    // get a list of installed apps.
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
        if (pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName) != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
            String applicationName = (String) (packageInfo != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(packageInfo)
                    : "(unknown)");
            Log.d(TAG, "Launch Name :" + applicationName);
        }
    }
```

So before launching the play you can maintain a list of all application that are present. And then it returns to your app you can again scan and check if the app was installed.

or you can implement

[Android receiver example for package install/remove/replace](http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/1335/)

Comment: maybe I did not make myself clear. My app is a website. It is not on a native app or a webview. It is a website opened on a regular mobile browser. What you refer to is a native app with a webview, which is not the case