# Installing an android app to launch a browser with initial user parameters

Tags: android, web-applications, google-play, apk

I've developed a small android app, that just launches a web site through a browser (No webView). This works well. 
Next, I need to distribute the android app link (installed in google play).
Each user needs to have a different link with his own registration key. 
Is it possible that the APK file will receive a parameter through the link (like query string and $_GET in the web) the parameter needs to be saved until the first time the app is being used by that user.(After the first time, the user information will be stored in a web cookie)

Comment: you can bind the key to the String value and save it in shared preference that will be stored in application. When user will get registered update the url string with appending the key like 
String URLString="my_url_string"+userkey;

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand, my link looks like this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xxx, how is the unique key get passed? is it like on the web ?id=com.xxx&key=123456 and how do I bind the key to the String? how do I read the key in the app (on web I would use $_GET)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the UTM referrer values in the link to the market. The market passes those values to the app. You get those values by creating a receiver that process "com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" broadcast.

You can find more information here:

- Creating the URL: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/devguide#google-play-builder
- Sample question on creating the receiver and debugging it with what you need: [Android App A wants to track Google Play referral data for Android App B installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986320/android-app-a-wants-to-track-google-play-referral-data-for-android-app-b-install)