# Get notified about install from Play Store page that opened by intent from my app

Tags: android, google-play

I want to advertise some other apps from my own installed app by providing user opportunity to hit button which sends intent to open advertised app page in Play Store.

I need to know whether user installed app from my intent or just leaved Play Store.

I know that I can register receiver to listen `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL`. But in this case I cant be sure that app is installed exactly from my intent. Because user can close Play Store page opened by my intent, see advertise in some other place, again open the same Play Store page and then install app, but that app install will be unrelated to my advertise.

Also I can start Play Store intent with `startActivityForResult`, but if user press home button, then Play Store activity goes background and I wont get `onActivityResult`, meanwhile user can install same app from unrelated to my app advertise.

Also I looked at Google Analytics referral functional. The problem with this is that information about install referral can be extracted only in the installed advertised app, not in my app that opened Play Store page. Therefore, at least I required force using Google Analytics in advertised app and ask their developers to send me information from their install statistic and trust that data. Seems like in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986320/android-app-a-wants-to-track-google-play-referral-data-for-android-app-b-install) people say that referral data can be extracted in app that created referral link, not only in app that installed by this link, but I cant get this to work, or misunderstood something.

I heard that in `iOS` my goal can be achieved by using new `AppStatistics` service.

Comment: Once you have launched another app, you cannot have its activity(action) log. AFAIK, its impossible to know this. However, you can use `WebView` instead of play store app to track its activity.

Comment: @JibranKhan in general case I understand that I cant track other activities actions, but I think maybe there is some special service or special intent to achieve my goal

Comment: Please have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817030/get-android-google-analytics-referrer-tag/3945100#3945100, may be it can put you on the right track

Comment: @JibranKhan thanks. I already looked at Google Analytics reference functional. The problem with this is that information about install referrer can be extracted only in the installed advertised app, not in my app that opened Play Store page. Therefore, at least I required force using Google Analytics in advertised app and ask their developers to send me information from their install statistic and trust that data.